# Mysql Primary key not working?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

In my mysql table i have given primary key for

```
id (int)(auto_incremet)
mobile_number(bigint)
email(varchar)
```

but i can enter same email and mobile number again. it is not returning an error. I want the email and mobile number as unique in my table. But duplicate values are also allowed even after setting the primary key.

the code i used was

```
    create table sample(id int(11) auto_increment,
           mobile bigint(20),email varchar(50),primary key(id,mobile,email));
```

while describing it is shown as primary key for all three..

where i go wrong.. suggest me a sollution please .. Thank you

Comment: Looks like there is a syntax error in your `create table` statement.

Comment: yup !! create table missing closing parenthesis :-)

Comment: i updated it .. actually the error is when i am inserting values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have it, only the *combination* of `id`, `mobile_number` and `email` is required to be unique.

Use the `id` as the primary key and set additional unique constraints on the `email` and `mobile_number` columns:

```
CREATE TABLE my_db.sample (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  mobile_number BIGINT(20) NULL,
  email VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE INDEX mobile_number_UNIQUE (mobile_number ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX email_UNIQUE (email ASC));
```

Comment: Thank  you .. .. any suggetions to add unique to an existing table ? like alter table

Comment: [`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)

Answer (score 4):

Here you are creating a primary key by using the combination of id, mobile and email. So as per the definition of primary key, these three attributes (id, mobile, email) combined used to distinguish between any two rows and **id for every row is unique as it is set to auto increment** so even if the email and mobile values for two or more rows are same, the combination of id, mobile and email is unique.

In order to get what you want you can do like this

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  mobile_number BIGINT(20) NULL UNIQUE,
  email VARCHAR(50) NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

`primary key(id,mobile,email)` means that the *tuple* of these three columns is a primary key. That means that all *tuples* in the table should be distinct, i.e. you cannot have two rows with same `id` *and* `mobile` *and* `email`. However, it's perfectly fine if two rows have same `email` while having different `id`.

If you want each column to be unique, you should specify that separately for each column with [`UNIQUE` constraint on a column](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE TABLE sample(id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
           mobile BIGINT(20),email VARCHAR(50),PRIMARY KEY(id,mobile,email));
```

The last face of your sql is missing brackets